# What does force do in the Set-AzureDeployment powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure

I am unable to find any documentation about what the force parameter does in the powershell command Set-AzureDeployment.

> Set-AzureDeployment [-Upgrade] [-ServiceName]  [-Package]
>    [-Configuration]  [-Slot]  [[-Mode] 
>   ] [[-Label]  ] [[-RoleName]  ] **[[-Force]]**
>   [[-ExtensionConfiguration]  ] [
>   ]

Has anyone else been able to find documentation around this, or have experience of what it actually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`Upgrade Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460793.aspx) which is implemented by `Set-AzureDeployment` Cmdlet, here's what I found regarding `Force` parameter:

> Indicates whether the update should proceed even when it will cause
>   local data to be lost from some role instances. True if the update
>   should proceed; otherwise false.
>
> The Force element is only available using version 2011-10-01 or
>   higher.